# remove function doesn't remove as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var offset = 0;
var delay = 100;    
$(document).ready(function(){

    for(let z=0;z<=6;z++){
        setDelay(z);
        delay += 100;
    }

    function setDelay(z) {
        setTimeout(function(){

            //Create clone
            var c2 = $(".cHeader").eq(0).clone().appendTo("#contact");

            //Set position
            offset += 20;
            $(c2).css("left", offset+"px");

        }, delay);

    }

    $(".cHeader").first().remove();

});
```

I am trying to create a clone of an element every 100ms until it reaches 7, and remove the very first one after creating 7 clones.
 The code above can create 7 clones without any problems, but when I add `$(".cHeader").first().remove();` to remove the first element, it removes every element with cHeader class. But I only want it to remove the first element with cHeader class.

Html:

```
<div id="contact">
    <h1 class="cHeader">hdr</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: What I see is:  do some code later, remove the first one, start the later code: clone the first - oh, doesn't exist.  So it's not "removing every element" - it's removing the first so there's nothing to clone.

Comment: Please let me understand what is your scope of using after *some time this happen* and then some

Answer (score 1):

> it removes every element with cHeader class.

it's actually removing the header before you can clone so there's nothing to clone.

This code:

```
 setTimeout(cloneHeader, 100)
 removeHeader()
```

is the same as:

```
 removeHeader()
 cloneHeader()
```

ie the removeHeader() is called *before* the cloneHeader code so there's nothing to clone.

You can instead *hide* the header, eg:

```
$(".cHeader").first().hide()
```

then when you clone:

```
var c2 = $(".cHeader").eq(0).clone().appendTo("#contact");
c2.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `setInterval` rather than `setTimeout` you can avoid globals, and also have the code more readable ( I believe ).

Also, move the `$('.cHeader').first().remove()` to be called *after* the 7 loops, so that the element remains for you to clone from - before you were removing it just before the start of the first loop

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function cloneElements() {
    let i = 0;
    let cloneInterval = setInterval(() => {
      // Create clone
      let count = $('#contact .cHeader').length;
      let c2 = $(".cHeader").first().clone().appendTo("#contact");

      // Set position
      c2.css('left', `${count * 20}px`);

      // Stop after 7
      i = i + 1;
      if (i >= 7) {
        clearInterval(cloneInterval);
        $('.cHeader').first().remove();
      }
    }, 100);
  }

  cloneElements();

});
```

```css
.cHeader {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="contact">
  <h1 class="cHeader">hdr</h1>
</div>
```